# Enlarge linked images on click

Tags: image

I am saving only names of image to the database while the image themselves are saved to a folder.These images are then displayed back in a php page in reduced size using the width, height tags.

I fetch them like this:

```
<?php echo '<img src="./images/'.$cfilename.'" width="300" height="400" />';  ?>
```

Is there a script I can include in php to enlarge the previews of the images when clicked on?

I have searched the web but allI found were scripts that demonstrated image names imbeded within html.

Any suggestion?

Joseph

Comment: hi Joseph, it is really hard to understand your final goal, are you looking for some javascript script which could detect acctual image size, or somewhat?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. Similar to fancy box: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/